# Entity framework 6 seed Arabic Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, arabic-support

I'm using MVC 5 with Entity framework 6

I create a lot of tables and seed the required data, if data language id in English, every thing is OK. but If I change the data to Arabic then Unknown letter is stored in DB

Example:
If I seed in `Name = "Abdallah"` it will be stored correctly
If I seed in `Name = "عبدالله"` It will display Unknown letters

**Note:** If I use the web interface (view) to set the field `Name = "عبدالله"` it will store the value correctly

The project is works correctly without any errors

Comment: Is it stored in db table properly or is it a problem rendering ?

Comment: its stored as `ÚÈÏÇááå`

Comment: databsae collation is `Arabic_CI_AS`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by using the second solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34622998/6424376)

1. Open Configuration.cs file.
2. Select advanced save options [advanced save options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKzMi.png)
3. Then, Select utf-8 and save file [utf-8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7m2w.png)
4. run `update-databse` command.